# End-to-end testing of distributed applications

Tags: continuous-integration, integration-testing, distributed-computing, end-to-end

Consider there is a new scenario/workflow and I want to test it for the whole enterprise. This implies I have to create a separate testing environment where all services will be deployed.

**But how do I specify which branches of every repository must be built and deployed? What are the automation options?**

Let it be two repositories for the services `A` and `B`.
How many testing environments do I need?

- `A.master-B.master`
- `A.master-B.feature`
- `A.feature-B.master`
- `A.feature-B.feature`

It seems like some combinations may be unnecessary. For example if features of `A` and `B` are unrelated, `A.feature-B.feature` can be omitted.

So for every branch of repository `X` we at least should test integration with currently deployed versions of services. It is a regression testing. And it is more or less clear how to automate it as we do not need to change the configuration. Just build `X.featureN` get other currently deployed artefacts, deploy them to new environment, test. Do it regularly. Profit!

But what about testing new scenario being developed?

In that case the set of branches for build and deployment must be provided explicitly. On the other hand each service has its own schedule, and feature branch is usually deleted after being merged into master. Can tags help here? We either find tag in master or in a feature branch (hopefully in a single one).